# WatchKit InterfaceController vs ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Are `awakeWithContext, willActivate, didDeactivate` the same as `viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear` in terms of functionality?

I am porting code from a Swift Apple Watch tutorial that was created back when people had to add their own watch AppViewController file to test their watch apps.

The included files and things have changed with the official watch release of Xcode obviously so I’m wondering where to put where.

For example there is some code in the older AppViewController file and so I just copy/pasted it into the new InterfaceController. I put code that was in `viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear` into `awakeWithContext, willActivate, didDeactivate` respectively.

It seems the methods are different. I got 1 error saying that setText doesn’t exist:
`bpmLabel.setText(currentBeatPattern.bpm) = "\(currentBeatPattern.bpm)"`

…and 2 errors saying view doesn’t exist:
`iconLabel.frame = self.view.bounds`
`self.view.insertSubview(iconLabel, atIndex: 1)`

It’s like WatchKit doesn’t use some of the normal property methods or something.

Error Messages:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhod2.png

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    self.view.insertSubview(iconLabel, atIndex: 1)  // Xcode error

}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()

    iconLabel.frame = self.view.bounds  // Xcode error

    iconLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    iconLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(132)
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()

    newBeat()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("newBeat"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    beat()

}


func newBeat() {
    // 1
    if ++currentBeatPatternIndex == beatPatterns.count {
        currentBeatPatternIndex = 0
    }

    // 2
    currentBeatPattern = beatPatterns[currentBeatPatternIndex]

    // 3
    bpmLabel.setText(currentBeatPattern.bpm) = "\(currentBeatPattern.bpm)"   // Xcode error

    iconLabel.text = currentBeatPattern.icon
}

func beat() {
    // 1
    UIView.animateWithDuration(currentBeatPattern.duration / 2,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: .CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: {
            // 2
            self.iconLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(
                self.iconLabel.transform, self.shrinkFactor, self.shrinkFactor)
        },
        completion: { _ in
            // 3
            UIView.animateWithDuration(self.currentBeatPattern.duration / 2,
                delay: 0.0,
                options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                animations: {
                    // 4
                    self.iconLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(
                        self.iconLabel.transform, self.expandFactor, self.expandFactor)
                },
                completion: { _ in
                    // 5
                    self.beat()
                }
            )
        }
    )
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that awakeWithContext, willActivate, and didDeactivate are very similar to the existing UIViewController methods like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, and viewDidUnload. The errors you're seeing however are related to the way WatchKit currently works. In order for a watch app to run, all the code is executed on an iPhone but the Apple Watch itself assumes responsibility for the UI elements. What that means is that any views that constitute your watch app MUST be included on your watch app's storyboard. Also, as a direct result, views cannot be instantiated and added to a parent view. All UI elements must be included in your watch app's storyboard and the watch will lay them out based on their arrangement in interface builder. This means you cannot call addSubview and you cannot set an element's frame. You can only adjust its size and set its hidden property to hide or show it on the watch. As far as this method goes –

```
 bpmLabel.setText(currentBeatPattern.bpm) = "\(currentBeatPattern.bpm)"
```

You are calling the method wrong. In swift the parameters are included in the parentheses. You can call it this way if it's what you mean

```
bpmLabel.setText("\(currentBeatPattern.bpm)")
```

but setText is a method that takes a string parameter and cannot be assigned with =

As far as the animations go, I think you're out of luck. Watch apps currently are more like widgets than iOS apps and things like UIView animations and frame math are not available you. You should definitely read 
up on WatchKit because there's no way you'll be able to port an iOS app directly to the watch like this.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So let's backup. I start a new project. Keep everything the way it was that way I have all my animations like you said. From that point how do I simply get it to show up in InterfaceController?  Second situation: If I got rid of animation and had text only would I be able to ditch the iPhone since the wrist sensor works without the iPhone?

Comment: No the iPhone must be present - it's the thing that is executing your logic. The only way to access a UI element in the WKInterfaceController is to add the element to the watch app's storyboard and access it through an IBOutlet. Do not plan on animating anything other than through a series of images or some clever text or background color magic. Watch apps are essentially a fancy repurposed today widget - not a full iOS app.

Comment: Also you said "All UI elements must be included in your watch app's storyboard and the watch will lay the out based on their arrangement in interface builder." You mean I can just copy and paste the UI elements from Main.storyboard to Interface.storyboard or do they need to be their own new elements? I can just paste them willy-nilly?

Comment: Watch Kit has its own set of UI elements and they are not the same as they would be on an iOS storyboard. You cannot copy paste.

Comment: No problem. Definitely read the docs. Watch apps are a different beast altogether. They're not especially difficult but the main challenge right now is working with WatchKit's limitations - of which there are currently many.

Comment: If you're making a watch app, that code is going to go in a WKInterfaceController.

Comment: Yeah. "iconLabel.frame = self.view.bounds" cannot work no matter what. Same goes for all the Animate methods. You're gonna have to read the docs to figure out how you might be able to fake the equivalent. But just keep in mind iPhone =/= Apple Watch. Copy pasted code is pretty much certain to fail. It's a totally different platform when it comes to views and interface elements. You're gonna have to rework almost all of that code.